# projectA ZIP file install on projectB build - maven

Tags: maven, aem

i have projectA artifacts in local maven repository.
Added projectA as dependency for projectB

When i do mvn clean install on projectB, I would like to have projectA zip file also installed onto my localhost.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Do you mean you want to compile install project A again while you give clean install for projectB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include it as sub package in the configuration of "content-package-maven-plugin" AKA "vault plugin". This will be present in the content package module, the "ui.apps" module in case you use Adobe maven archetype.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
<artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    ...
    <subPackages>
        <subPackage>
            <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
            <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-content</artifactId>
            <filter>true</filter>
        </subPackage>
    </subPackages>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Reference : https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/pages/maven.html.

Including sub packages have a weird side effect when rolling back to a previous version of your parent package and the revert opertaion ends up in errors [try it out, will know what I meant ].

Just declaring "projectA" as an explicit dependency for your package in vault plugin settings will warn your users that the instance is missing required package when they try to install it via package manager. This approach is not as neat as the sub package one, but does not hinder revert operations.

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
 <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
   ...
  <properties>
     <dependencies>
      <!--has to be in a single line -->
      adobe/cq60:core.wcm.components.all:1.0.6,adobe/consulting:acs-aem-commons-content:3.14.4
     </dependencies>
  </properties>
  ...
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Additional reference : https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/vlt-mavenplugin.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was not successful with subpackage , projectA bundle, zip file getting dowloaded to m2 repository but not installing to AEM package manager, admin console. Could you please point me at the correct content-package-maven plugin, i have this artifactId mentioned 7 times in my projectB ui.apps, ui.content, parent pom files. I tried to put properties tag after subPackages, but properties tag does not accept String type, rather Map it seems. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have updated the answer with example. The properties part was to declare it as dependency not make it a sub package. [that also had an error, has been fixed]

Comment: Thanks again, Can you point me to xsd where I could find the xml elements that are allowed in content package maven plugin?  I will try <properties> with <dependencies> , Any idea why subpackage is not working for me ? i do not see any errors in projectB autoInstallPackage

Comment: Post your content package plugin config and dependency. Link to the settings option https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/vlt-mavenplugin.html

Comment: Adding <filter root="/etc/packages/projectA" /> worked for subpackages configuration. Another optios is, which worked. <execution><id>install-cmp</id><configuration><groupId>com.companyname</groupId<artifactId>projectA.ui.apps</artifactId><packaging>zip</packaging<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version></configuration> <goals><goal>install</goal></goals></execution>